# PHP how to tally column to specific user

Tags: php

I have a problem. I am creating a booking system. I have 2 tables:

```
Table user(
    userid int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar,
    password varchar,
    phone varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

Table booking(
    book_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userid int,
    timeslot varchar,
    date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user(userid)
);
```

How to make book_id column from table "booking" tally to userid column from table "user"?

What i mean is whenever the user made a booking, the book_id will always will be his.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a foreign key, looks like you need to fix a lot of things first, maybe make a little diagram and then learn some basic SQL syntax.

Comment: actually i kinda confuse with my system .. but the thing is , roughly said, my system provide users to make a booking.
Lets say I have 2 users, and 2 bookings.The book_id 1 tally to the userid 1. The book_id 2 tally to the userid 2. So it's all tally.

When i delete 1 booking, and I add another booking , so the book_id will become 3 but the userid only has 2. So,its not tally anymore. Hopefully u understand me. Thanks for the reply.